# How do I install Azure Powershell *on* an Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: powershell, cloud, azure

I have need for a cloud based intranet application to run Azure Powershell. I've done a bunch of digging and I cannot find anywhere that gives me an understanding of the process I need to follow to actually get Azure Powershell to install on my Cloud Service machine so that my app can interact with and manage my Azure environment.

If I run the application with my Azure Powershell scripts locally, everthing is fine, but I cannot for the life of me get it to function correctly on Azure.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get when trying to function it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Chocolatey via a startup task in the web role and then had that install the Web Platform Installer command line tool and from here used that to install the Azure Powershell tools. Once the install was complete in a post-deploy script, Powershell initiates a reboot so that the Azure Powershell tools become properly available.